# column with just space getting purged in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a query like the following

```
val query = "select 'a' as col_1, ' ' as col_2, col_3,col_4 from mytable"
val df = sqlContext.sql(query)
```

Now, if I display the dataframe, it is the following :

```
col_1|col_2|col_3|col_4
a| |test|test
a| |testa|testa
a| |testb|testb
```

This is as expected.  However, if I write this dataframe to disk

```
df.write
.option("sep",",")
.csv(file)
```

The file contains the following:

```
a,\"\",test,test
a,\"\",testa,testb
a,\"\",testb,testb
```

The second column is incorrect, it should just be a single space, no quotes or anything.

How can I avoid this? I want my file outputted as :

```
a, ,test,test
a, ,testa,testb
a, ,testb,testb
```

Executable code test -

```
val tempview = "temptest"
val path = "/mnt/test/"
var df = Seq(
  (8, "bat"),
  (64, "mouse"),
  (-27, "horse")
).toDF("number", "word")

df.createOrReplaceTempView(tempview)

df = sqlContext.sql("select 'a' as first, ' ' as second, number, word from temptest")

df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).option("sep", ",").csv(path)
val l = dbutils.fs.ls(path)
val file = l(l.size - 1)
val output = dbutils.fs.head(path + file.name)
println(output)
```

Output is - `a,\"\",-27,horse`

Expected output - `a, ,-27,horse`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to resolve this by not saving as CSV. Try saving as a more robust (i.e. typed) data format, such as parquet or orc.

I don't know how strings are treated in the Spark CSV serializer, but it's very possible that anything with a space is double quoted.

In my experience the CSV library in Spark, while pretty good, is not hugely configurable. You just take what you get. I've had to load data as RDD and then parse before because of lack of configurability. CSV is not the best data format for Spark.

Comment: I agree, but part of my requirement is the output has to be a text based file.

Comment: In that case Spark isn't ideal but can solve you problem by applying a map operation that joins and formats the rows into comma separated values.